# $K$ cannot have subfields $k'$ and $k''$ such $k' \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and $k'' \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$ where $p$ is some prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Prove that a field $K$ cannot have subfields $k'$ and $k''$ such $k' \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and $k'' \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$ where $p$ is some prime.

I have tried this by contradiction. Let $K$ a field with subfields $k'$ and $k''$ such $k' \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and $k'' \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$ for $p$ a prime. Then I consider the prime field of $K$, lets say $k$ is the prime field of $K$. So by a field theory result we have that $k \cong \mathbb{Q}$ or $k \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$ for some prime $p$ depending if $K$ has characteristic $0$ or $p$ respectively. Without lost of generality lets say that $k \cong Q$ (K has characteristic 0), and $k$ is by definition the smallest of all subfields of $K$, we have that $k \subseteq k'$ and $k \subseteq k''$. But as $k''$ has characteristics $p$ as $k'' \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$ by hypothesis and $k''$ contains a subfield of order $0$ as $k \subseteq k''$ with $k \cong Q$ we contradict the following fact

[The characteristics of a subfield of a field is same as that of the field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175103/the-characteristics-of-a-subfield-of-a-field-is-same-as-that-of-the-field)

We can obtain an analogous contradiction  supposing $k \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$. Proving that  $K$ cannot have subfields $k'$ and $k''$ such $k' \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and $k'' \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}$ where $p$ is some prime.

Is my proof free of any mistakes? Thanks!

Comment: You are invoking too much, though essentially correct (in a “scratch your left ear by using your right hand draped above your head” correctness kind of way). The $1$ of $K$ is the same as the $1$ of $k’$ and $k’’$. But in $k’’$, $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($p$ times) is $0$, and in $\mathbb{Q}$ it is not. (The isomorphisms are required to map $1_{k’}$ to $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $1_{k’’}$ to $1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

Answer (score 2):

You did a lot more work than you really need. It is really easy to see that in general the characteristic of a subfield is the same as the characteristic of the original field. So if you had such $k'$ and $k''$ then what would be the characteristic of $K$? If it is $0$ then it contradicts the existence of $k''$, if it is a prime number it contradicts the existence of $k'$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but *extremely* roundabout. The prime subfield of $K$ is by definition the intersection of all its subfields; so your proof uses the simple fact that the intersection of two subfields is again a subfield. This simple fact is all you need:

It implies that $k=k'\cap k''$ is a subfield of both $k'=\Bbb{Q}$ and $k''=\Bbb{F}_p$. But both fields have no proper subfields. It follows that
$$\Bbb{Q}=k'=k=k''=\Bbb{F}_p,$$
a contradiction.

Or an even simpler proof using the linked question; if such $k'$ and $k''$ exist then
$$0=\operatorname{char}k'=\operatorname{char}K=\operatorname{char}k''=p,$$
a contradiction.

**Edit:** As for the correctness; I just noticed you wrote that

> *...$k''$ contains a subfield of order $0$...*

I think you mean *characteristic $0$* here.